# powerpivot excel sheets in Sharepoint online?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, excel-services, powerpivot

We have finally decided to move SharePoint On prem to SharePoint Online. In our on prem site we have BI site where we house 15-20 excel sheets which utlize powerpivot within them which gets refreshed every night.

Since we are moving to SharePoint online, what are the process of migrating them to sharepoint online, if it is supported. If it is not supported what are workarounds or alternate ways to display those in SharePoint online.

Answer (score 2):

PowerPivot is not available in SharePoint Online. The alternative would be Power BI or using PowerPivot for Excel only. If using PP for Excel, your users would need to open the Excel sheet in the client.